# How do I specify required fields in appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I have my `appsettings.json` which works perfectly except it doesn't allow me to control if value present or not.

Today I faced a bug because I forgot to put one variable in config and it didn't say. It just used default field value and it was ok locally, but crashed on another machine.

I came with following solution:

```
private static T Deserialize<T>(IConfigurationRoot configuration, string sectionName) where T : new()
{
    var result = new T();
    var configurationSection = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
    configurationSection.Bind(result);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(result);
        if (value == null || value is string s && s == "")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"All configuration fields are required but {propertyInfo.Name} is missing");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it obviosly won't work for value types. It also won't work with values that intentionally are nulls or empty string. I need original JSON representation or some API to validate field presence, but I haven't find it.

I tried to get JSON from sections to parse it via `Newtonsoft.Json` but again with no success.

Any suggestions how it could be done?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [options validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-validation).

Comment: Make the value types nullable and this will work fine.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Options looks like they could work, but yet another wrapper. Why do I need `IOption<T>` on the first place here? I thought they are only required for hot reloads and stuff. I'd generally like to have my model independed from knowing anything about extensibility infrastructure.

Comment: That's all fine. If you don't like the options wrapper and such, options validation isn't for you.